# How to control a Wi-fi voice transmission? (gstreamer)

Tags: linux, networking, audio, c++, gstreamer

I am trying to build a telephony transmission through Wi-Fi What i am trying to do is, connect a programmable Wi-Fi Headset( it does not really exist,it is actually a Linux computer) with a cellphone which is also Wi-Fi enabled.( this doesnt exist either and it is a Linux computer as well ). This is like the case where one has a cellphone which is paired with a Bluetooth-pairing device and when you get a phonecall you can control the call establishment and abortion using the headset itself. the difference is that i want to use Wi-Fi instead of Bluetooth. So what i have done so far is implement a Media stream in Gstreamer that can send stereo Voice signals over IP.( i.e VoIP in a local wireless network) . Here is the sender Pipeline:

```
gst-launch -v  alsasrc ! audioconvert ! audio/x-raw-int,
channels=2,depth=16,width=16,rate=44100 ! rtpL16pay ! udpsink 
host=192.168.178.110 port=5000  //sender
```

And on the receiving end i have done the following, to Listen on a UDP port to receive the voice signals and do the decoding and play them back:

```
    gst-launch udpsrc port=5000 ! "application/x-rtp,media=(string)audio,
    clock-rate=(int)44100, encoding-name=(string)L16, 
    channels=(int)2, payload=(int)96" ! rtpL16depay !
    audioconvert ! alsasink    //receiver
```

If i run the two streams manually on each end i receive my stereo signals and by swapping the two pipelines to be run in a separate Terminal on each Linux computer , i can have a real-time Speech between the two Linux computers.

The problem with this is that i have to run the pipelines manually on each Linux to establish a bi-directional connection and as we all know in a Bluetooth pairing, after pairing no further steps has to be done manually by the users to connect the cellphone with the head-set .Some type of signaling is used that initializes send/receive process on each end.That means when the cellphone rings the headset is notified that an incoming call is coming through on the cellphone.

Now my question is what is the proper way to this automation process that when i want to establish a call from one of the Linux computers to the other one , the other end be notified that a Linux with specified characters( for example xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx IP and xxxx Port number) is trying to connect, and after acknowledgement of the other end the above-mentioned pipelines start streaming the Audio, bidirectionally and hang-up when one end, ends the conversation.